# What is the return value of the expect(" ") method in Expect4j?

Tags: java

I am trying to login into CISCO IOS routers through my java application.
A few weeks back I got zero as the 'returnValue' on a successful match and a -2 when the match was wrong.

```
         expect.send(password+NEW_LINE);
         returnValue=expect.expect("XYZ#");
```

where 'XYZ#' is the prompt of the command line which we see once we have given the right password and logged in.
It was working fine but now I see a -3 as the 'returnValue' even when the 'expectation' is correct and the same value again when the 'expectation' is incorrect.

What is the value returned when the match is correct? 
The description says- returns the 'number' of times the pattern is found, or an error code

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=expect4j&g=com.github.cverges&v=1.7) or [source code](https://github.com/cverges/expect4j/blob/master/src/main/java/expect4j/Expect4j.java):

> `static int RET_UNKNOWN = -1;` An error code returned by Expect4j.expect to indicate that some unforeseen condition occurred.
>
> `static int RET_TIMEOUT = -2;` An error code returned by Expect4j.expect to indicate that the timeout value expired prior to finding a concluding match.
>
> `static int RET_EOF = -3;` An error code returned by Expect4j.expect to indicate that the end of file marker was encountered when accessing the reader stream.
>
> `static int RET_TRIED_ONCE = -4;` An error code returned by Expect4j.expect to indicate that no match was found and no re-attempt was made.

So you can handle errors like this:

```
// ...
int returnValue = expect.expect("XYZ#");
if(returnValue < 0){
    switch(returnValue){
        case Expect4j.RET_UNKNOWN: {
            // handle error
            break;
        }
        case Expect4j.RET_TIMEOUT: {
            // handle error
            break;
        }
        case Expect4j.RET_EOF: {
            // handle error
            break;
        }
        case Expect4j.RET_TRIED_ONCE: {
            // handle error
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it return a zero on success?

Comment: @user3824001 no, just some non-negative number

Comment: If it was helpful, then please accept this answer. Thanks!